# Null Coalesce with colors

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

```
protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        // this.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        base.BackColor = _colors.SelectedBackColor ?? base.BackColor;
        base.ForeColor = _colors.SelectedForeColor ?? base.BackColor;
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }
```

The error I get is

> Error 519 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Drawing.Color' and 'System.Drawing.Color'

I thought it had to be 2 matching type for a null coalesce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null coalesce operator cannot be applied to non-nullable value types. If you would like to make this work, you should make `SelectedBackColor` and `SelectedForeColor` in your `_colors` class nullable:

```
public Color? SelectedBackColor {get;set;}
public Color? SelectedForeColor {get;set;}
```

Now coalesce operator `??` works as expected. Moreover, the compiler has enough information to determine that `_colors.SelectedForeColor ?? base.BackColor` never returns `null`, making the assignment to a property of non-nullable type legal.

Answer (score 7):

[`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) is a struct and therefor can never be null. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: @CalvinSmith no: it isn't

Comment: @CalvinSmith It may be `default(Color)` (that is the value you get for properties and fields if you don't explicitly set a value) but it is not null.

Comment: @MarcGravell So if I get a null color, that makes me like, awesome?

Comment: @CalvinSmith yes, because `System.Drawing.Color` isn't a reference type in the first place. You can't *have* a "color reference", unless you mean `ref Color` or `Color*`, which is not the same meaning of the word.

Comment: is `_colors` null? You don't tell us what that is and if that was null you could easily get a NullRefrenceException (If that is the [real problem you are trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @CalvinSmith If, however, you actually have a `Color?` (aka `Nullable<Color>`), then it *still* isn't a "color reference"